# Get a PHAsset from ReferenceURL: fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:options:) DEPRECATED

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

My goal is to upload original resolution device captured video files to S3 using AWSS3TransferUtility.

User selects a video using `UIImagePickerController` however, if I pass `info[UIImagePickerControllerMEDIAURL]` to the transferUtility it always reduces the video to 720p. If I pass the transferutility `info[UIImagePickerControllerREFERENCEURL]` I get an Error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 4.)

Cannot find an explanation of the error code so I am assuming it is a **permissions** error because I am not accessing the asset via the **Photos** framework or `PHAsset.fetch`

- REFERNCE URL -
  assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=5B99DC8E-B94E-4CBF-AFB8-7F82BC72FEE2&ext=mov
- MEDIA URL -
  file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/76928AD7-F142-4CC9-9708-A58C8CAF8EE5/tmp/trim.82038B6A-222F-4B50-A937-A8C399B02A08.MOV

Now, I have the ReferenceURL, and am trying to get the PHAsset so that I can copy it the Documents Directory and pass the URL of it to TransferUtility from there to get around the **AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 4**.

However, [fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:options:) is now deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset/1624782-fetchassets) so  I cannot fetch the asset with the ReferenceURL; all the other methods are batch fetching via media type, etc. There is [fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset/1624732-fetchassets) but I am not sure how to get the local identifier of a PHAsset just from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `PHAsset` of selected item, you can get it directly from `info` in `UIImagePickerController` callback

```
let asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset
```

if it is not there, then you did not request authorization *before* using picker, so do this

```
let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

if status == .notDetermined  {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in

    })
}
```

*Note: `localIdentifier` is a property of `PHObject`, and `PHAsset` is a subclass of `PHObject`.*